Colored underline and overline in math mode
I am trying to write a style sheet that will define the commends \undercolor{math here}{<color>} and \overcolor{math here}{<color>}.
I had thought this would be very easy, and got this document:
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e} \ProvidesPackage{overcolor}

\RequirePackage{xcolor}

\newcommand\overcolor[2]{\colorlet{temp}{.}\color{#2}\overline{\color{temp}#1}\color{temp}}

\newcommand\undercolor[2]{\colorlet{temp}{.}\color{#2}\underline{\color{temp}#1}\color{temp}}

This works fine, on, say:
\documentclass{article} \usepackage{amsmath} \usepackage{overcolor}

\begin{document}

Here is an example of the \emph{overcolor} package:

\begin{align*}
    a &= (\undercolor{b}{violet}+\undercolor{c}{red}) + (\undercolor{d}{red} - \undercolor{b}{violet})\\
    &= \overcolor{0}{violet} + \overcolor{(c+d)}{red} \end{align*}


\end{document}

And produces:

Note that the underlines are all black though, not the correct color.
Why is this happening? The overcolor and undercolor commands are identical? What can I do instead?
Bonus points if you know of a slick way to have the code handle the choice of color. I only want this for keeping track of terms in math expressions, and don't care that much about the specific color, only want it to be visible, so if there was some way for \undercolor{math here}{1} to take a number, not a color, and then just have something like 1 -> nice color #1, 2 -> nice color #2, etc.
Thanks!

I'd first typeset the math, so color will not enter the scene and then add the overline or underline around the constructed box.
This allows nesting and also works for subscripts and superscripts.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\overcolor}{mm}{\mathpalette\overundercolor@{\overline{#1}{#2}}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\undercolor}{mm}{\mathpalette\overundercolor@{\underline{#1}{#2}}}
\newcommand{\overundercolor@}[2]{\overundercolor@@#1#2}
\newcommand{\overundercolor@@}[4]{%
  % #1 = math style
  % #2 = command
  % #3 = math material
  % #4 = color
  \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1#3$}%
  \mathcolor{#4}{#2{\usebox\z@}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
a &= (\undercolor{b}{violet}+\undercolor{c}{red})
   + (\undercolor{d}{red} - \undercolor{b}{violet})\\
  &= \overcolor{0}{violet} + \overcolor{(c+d)}{red} \\
  &= X_{\overcolor{u}{red}-\undercolor{v}{violet}} \\
  &= \overcolor{X_{\undercolor{z}{violet}}}{red} \\
  &= \mathcolor{green!70!blue}{\overcolor{X}{red}+Y}
\end{align*}

\end{document}


The version with color numbers:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\overcolor}{mm}{\mathpalette\overundercolor@{\overline{#1}{#2}}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\undercolor}{mm}{\mathpalette\overundercolor@{\underline{#1}{#2}}}
\newcommand{\overundercolor@}[2]{\overundercolor@@#1#2}
\newcommand{\overundercolor@@}[4]{%
  % #1 = math style
  % #2 = command
  % #3 = math material
  % #4 = color number
  \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1#3$}%
  \mathcolor{overundercolor#4}{#2{\usebox\z@}}%
}
\makeatother

\colorlet{overundercolor1}{violet}
\colorlet{overundercolor2}{red}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
a &= (\undercolor{b}{1}+\undercolor{c}{2})
   + (\undercolor{d}{2} - \undercolor{b}{1})\\
  &= \overcolor{0}{1} + \overcolor{(c+d)}{2} \\
  &= X_{\overcolor{u}{2}-\undercolor{v}{1}} \\
  &= \overcolor{X_{\undercolor{z}{1}}}{2} \\
  &= \mathcolor{green!70!blue}{\overcolor{X}{2}+Y}
\end{align*}

\end{document}


Would it be possible to add a fifth parameter, say    % #5 = thickness   to cover at the same time the requirement of this question about overline thickness ? Let me know if you think I should ask a separate question.

@J.-E.Pin That's a different task.

You already have a nice LaTeX answer that uses rules (overline and underline). I add here a way to do this with over and under accents. I only know how to do it in ConTeXt (lmtx), though, so it might not be applicable to you. But maybe someone else who passes the question will find it useful.
\definemathaccent
  [myunderaccents]
  [bottom:stretch]
  [color=green]

\definemathaccent
  [myoveraccents]
  [top:stretch]
  [symbolcolor=red]

\definemathbottomaccent[myunderaccents][myunder]["332]
\definemathtopaccent[myoveraccents][myover]["305]

\starttext

\startformula
a \alignhere
  =  (\myunder{a} + \myunder[symbolcolor=blue]{b})
  +  (\myunder[textcolor=red]{d} - \myunder[color=yellow]{b})
  \breakhere
  = \myover{0} + \myover[symbolcolor=orange]{(c + d)}
  \breakhere
  = X__{\myover[scale=no,stretch=no]{u} + \myover{u} - \myunder{v}}
\stopformula

\stoptext

As you see, it is possible to set the color of the whole construct with the colorkey, as well as the color of the accent (symbolcolor key) or the expression that has the accent (textcolor key). With the scale and stretch keys we control the outcome of the accents.

